# PWM object's ChangeDutyCycle method is not working

Tags: gpio, python-3, cars

I have a motor class
but I dont' know why this motor cannot change speed

```
class Motor:
    def __init__(self, pos, line_status=0):
        def set_motor_gpio(_a, _b, _pwm):
            self._A = _a
            self._B = _b
            self._PWM = _pwm
            GPIO.setup(self._A, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(self._B, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(self._PWM, GPIO.OUT)
            self.PWM = GPIO.PWM(self._PWM, 100)

                if pos == "L":
        if line_status == 0:
            set_motor_gpio(12, 11, 35)
        elif line_status == 1:
            set_motor_gpio(11, 12, 35)

        elif pos == "R":
            if line_status == 0:
                set_motor_gpio(13, 15, 37)
            elif line_status == 1:
                set_motor_gpio(15, 13, 37)

    def run(self, direction, speed):
        """
        Make motor run
        :param direction: Forward or Backward as String
        :param speed: running speed
        """
        if not (direction == "F" or "B"):
            raise Exception("run method's direction must be 'F' or 'B'")
        if direction == "F":
            GPIO.output(self._A, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(self._B, GPIO.LOW)
        elif direction == "B":
            GPIO.output(self._A, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(self._B, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(self._PWM, GPIO.HIGH)
            self.PWM.ChangeDutyCycle(speed)
```

I tested this code. before self.PWM.ChangeDutyCycle(speed), everything works. Although I assigned Motor to instance and Motor.run("F", 0), Motor ran. I think It should have stopped. Why is self.PWM.ChangeDutyCycle not working?

Comment: I do not know exactly what your hardware is, but the problem is very simple and you can see the link below.
http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-Direction-and-Speed-of-DC-Motor-Using-/

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it.
The problem was I didn't use self.PWM.start method.
self.PWM.ChangeDutyCycle must be executed after self.PWM.start() method executed once at least.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.